# BeautifulSoup: Extracting "alt" OR "title" fields from a gif

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The code below works at retrieving URL's from a page that contain a little gif named error.gif.  However, I want to extend the scrape a little further and I am having trouble pulling data associated with the error.gif.
On mouseOver the gif will present a small message, I would also like to obtain this popOut message, but my attempts have not been able to return any of their values.  I have checked BS' website and watched other tutorials, but I have not found or read about this matter anywhere else.  [SnapShot of error.gif details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq5Pw.png)

Essentially, I am trying to extract the "alt" field OR the "title" field and append it to the right of the hyperlink which has already been extracted.

### WORKING CODE

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://<site>").content, "html.parser") 
tables = soup.find('table', class_='serverTable') 
rows = tables.find_all('tr')   

for tr in rows:
    cols = tr.find_all('td')
    linkstr = str(cols)
    if 'error.gif' in linkstr:
        if not 'good.gif' in linkstr:
            if not '=&gt' in linkstr:
                for link in tr('a', href=True):

                    print("ERROR =>", link)
```

Comment: Please add link to that page

Comment: Please include a minimal sample of the HTML you are trying to parse. Btw, instead of what you're doing with `linkstr`, it would be better to use `find` or `find_all` to extract the `img` object, and then you will be able to get its `title` and `alt` attributes using BS API

Comment: Janus, I took a snapshot of the code I was having issues with, I cannot provide a direct link as this page is internally hosted and is not public facing.  While the code is not perfect, I am able to extract the data I would like.  The end goal for this script to scrape a page looking for error.gif, paste the results into a email template and email the results every hour or so.  Thank you and Rahul for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
errors = soup.find_all('img', {'src':'img/error.gif'})

for tag in errors:
   print(tag['title']) # or any attribute you want to extract from that tag.
```

Comment: Rahul, I cant provide a link, the page is hosted internally.  However, your code recommendation helped me extract the contents of the 'title' field I was having troubles with.  I marked your Answer as correct.  Thank you for taking the time to help me out.